# moment is not defined Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, grunt

Estoy intentando resolver este problema que marca cuando voy a `build grunt`... Estoy usando una `librería` de `bower_components` llamada `moment`. Estoy haciendo esto: `var moment;` pero no funciona no se que otro método puedo definir esta variable.

[image]

 Este es mi codigo app.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name virtualApp
 * @description
 * # virtualApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular.module('virtualApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngMap',
    'angular-carousel',
    'mdRangeSlider',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'auth0.lock',
    'angular-storage',
    'angular-jwt',
    'rzModule',
    'material.components.expansionPanels',
    'lr.upload',
    'md.data.table',
    'duScroll',
    'angularSpinner'
]).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$translateProvider', 
'lockProvider', '$mdThemingProvider', '$mdDateLocaleProvider', 'usSpinnerConfigProvider', 
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider, lockProvider, $mdThemingProvider, 
    $mdDateLocaleProvider, usSpinnerConfigProvider) {


    //var moment;


    moment.locale('es');



    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
        return date ? moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : null;
    };

    $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
        var m = moment(dateString, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);
        return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
    };




}]).run(['$rootScope', 'store', 'jwtHelper', '$route', '$http', 'lock', '$window', function($rootScope, store, jwtHelper, $route, $http, lock, $window) {



}]);
```

Comment: Hare la pregunta que todos preguntaran: Estas agregando la libreria [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js) a tu pagina/proyecto?

Comment: @Einer <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script> yes en mi index lo tengo agregado, funciona perfectamente, pero quiero evitar que cuando haga grunt me salga este warning

Comment: @Einer ya solucione mi problema gracias :D aparentemente hay un file en mi proyecto que se llama .jshintrc donde tiene un objeto "globals": { "moment" : false} con esto solucione agregando al objeto globals la variable moment :D

Comment: Que bueno fue oir eso. Suerte!

Comment: @Pablo Añádelo como respuesta, venía a ponerla yo pero ya que lo has solucionado estaría bien que lo hicieses tú, es un problema muy común. Por cierto, ten cuidado con añadir librerías que forman parte de las herramientas de desarrollo ("devDependencies") a tu aplicación como si fueran "dependencies" normales de tu package.json